# Impossible to login in wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to enter in the server side of my site in wordpress.org but it says "The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect." I changed my password with phpMyAdmin and I remove a plugin (theme-my-account) who gives me problem. Can you help me please? I don't know what to do

Comment: Is't there an other for "Forgotten Password"? it will send a reset link to your register Email ID. And you cannot change password through phpMyAdmin, only doing md5 will not work!

Comment: I have a big problem because a friend of mine suggest me to use name: admin which is, I think, the most common one in this case. When I try to use the mail it says that nothing is related to that mail

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to hash the password, before adding it to phpmyadmin. You can use [this website](http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4) to hash it.

Answer (score 0):

Must be encrypt your phpmyadmin password with md5 hash key .

Comment: Now my IP is also blocked and I have no idea how to enter in the jetpack settings

Comment: if the ip is block you can use proxy server for first time login then remove your ip from blocklist

Comment: Can you be more precise, please?

Comment: just create a new admin user by your phpmyadmin access. then try to login with using proxy browser. if you can login  successfully then remove your ip from blacklist. May be now you can understand.